# Combining powerpoint officer objects

Tags: officer

Using the code below, is there an easy way to combine presentations p1 and p2 together?

```
library(officer)
  library(magrittr)
  p1  = read_pptx() %>% add_slide(layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% ph_with_text(type = "body", str = "First Slide")

  p2  = read_pptx() %>% add_slide(layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% ph_with_text(type = "body", str = "Second Slide")
```

Comment: not with officer

Comment: can you do `p2  = p1 %>% add_slide(layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% ph_with_text(type = "body", str = "Second Slide")`?

Comment: The situation I have is two different officer objects that I want to combine. I just put the example above to provide a simple example of the type of variables I wanted to combine.